# Time complexity and proof of time complexity

Tags: asymptotics

Which is true and which false? I can't really decide which one is true and which false. Maybe in first 3 cases.

$$3n^5 − 16n + 2 \in O(n^5)$$
$$3n^5 − 16n + 2 \in O(n)$$
$$3n^5 − 16n + 2 \in \Omega(n^{17})$$
$$3n^5 − 16n + 2 \in \Omega(n^5)$$
$$3n^5 − 16n + 2 \in \Theta(n^5)$$
$$3n^5 − 16n + 2 \in \Theta(n)$$
$$3n^5 − 16n + 2 \in \Theta(n^{17})$$

and how to prove this one:

$$2^{(n+1)} \in O\left(\frac{3^n}n\right)$$

Comment: Have you checked the wiki page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $f(n) = O(g(n))$ iff for $n$ big enough it holds that $|f(n)|\leq M |g(n)|$ for some positive constant $M$. That is, if you deal with polynomials, 
$$
  P(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{m_1} a_k n^k,\quad Q(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{m_2} b_k n^k, \quad a_{m_1}, b_{m_2}>0
$$
the terms with the highest power dominate other terms and thus
$$
  P(n) = O(Q(n))\Leftrightarrow m_1\leq m_2
$$
which helps you resolving the first part of your question.

For the second part, apply similar analysis and show that for $n$ big enough it holds that
$$
  2^{n+1} \leq \frac{3^n}{n} \text{ that is } \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\leq \frac{1}{2n}
$$

Comment: $\frac1{2n}$ instead of $\frac2n$.

Comment: @Berci: thanks, fixed

Comment: how it is possible that this holds?
$ (\frac{2}{3})^n \le \frac{1}{2n} $

Comment: @user2212098: *for* $n$ *big enough*